# Exponer ACF en endpoint peronalizado de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, endpoint

estoy creando un endpoint personalizado con Wordpress, pero por mas que intento no logro exponer los campos adicionales de ACF que agregue a mi CPT, si alguien me pudiera dar un poco mas de luces estaría muy agradecido. :D

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'negocio', '/rubro(?:/(?P<rubro>\d+))?', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'negocios_data_rubro',
  ) );
} );
```

```
function negocios_data_rubro( $data ) {

    $args  = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'post_type'  => 'negocio',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'rubro',
                'value'   => $data['rubro'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $query->posts;
}
```

Comment: prueba agregando la versión al namespace `negocio/v1`, un log o vardump del array `$args` o `$data`que te dice? llega el valor de rubro?

Comment: Hola los datos del CPT llegan de manera correcta, los datos faltantes son los custom fields que agregue con ACF

Comment: ahi va un ejemplo con [`get_fields()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El resultado de `WP_Query` no incluye los meta, hay que agregarlos, algo así:

```
    $args  = [
      'post_type'  => 'negocio',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status'    => [ 'publish', 'future' ],
      'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'negocio_by_rubro' => [
          'key' => 'rubro',
          'value'   => $data['rubro'],
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ],
        // ... otros meta
      ],
      'orderby' => [
        'menu_order' => 'ASC',
        'negocio_by_rubro' => 'ASC',
      ],
    ];

    $Q = new WP_Query($args);
    $P = $Q->posts;
    $los_posts = [];

    if ($P){
      foreach( $P as $key => $el_post ){
        // traemos los fields acf delpost
        $F = get_fields($el_post);
        $los_posts[$key] = $el_post->to_array(); // agregamos el post al array
        $los_posts[$key]['fields'] = $F; // agregamos los fields al post
      }
    }

    return $los_posts; // retornamos los posts con fields
```